# Issue with Shotgun Gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, sinatra, rack, shotgun

I am having an issue connecting to the server using the shotgun GEM in ruby. Here is the error I get.

Can someone identify the issue here? Is it with the command I typed, or possibly something else? I have previously had issues with attempting to install the Ruby Bundle to run this lab. I had had assistance in troubleshooting that issue, but there still seems to be a possible issue with the GEM.

Antonio@MacBook-Pro sinatra-shotgun-server % rackup app.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
22: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>' 21: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in` eval'
20: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>' 19: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:297:in` activate_bin_path'
18: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:297:in `synchronize' 17: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:299:in` block in activate_bin_path'
16: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:236:in `finish_resolve' 15: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:435:in` resolve_current'
14: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:423:in `resolve' 13: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:192:in` resolve'
12: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:42:in `resolve' 11: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:64:in` resolve'
10: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:106:in `start_resolution' 9: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:165:in` initial_state'
8: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:51:in `sort_dependencies' 7: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:69:in` with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
6: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `block in sort_dependencies' 5: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:279:in` sort_dependencies'
4: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:279:in `with_index' 3: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:279:in` sort_by'
2: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:279:in `each' 1: from /Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:285:in` block in sort_dependencies'
/Users/Antonio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:235:in `search_for': Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'did_you_mean (= 1.3.0)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
Antonio@MacBook-Pro sinatra-shotgun-server %